# Convert unix date to utc

Tags: sql-server, datetime, utc, unix-timestamp, sql-date-functions

I have table with list of date, but date in unix format.
I need to convert unix time to utc.
The function FROM_UNIXTIME is not clear for me. Cause when i try to use it, i have error:
"FROM_UNIXTIME" is not recognized built-in function name

I create sql request:
select name, dateadd(hour,-5,(dateadd(SS,CONVERT(int,substring(call_connect_time,4,10)).'19700101'))) as call_time
from db

and i have error:
*argument data type datetime is invalid for argument 1 of substring function.*

Do you have any idea what should i do?

Comment: Unix timestamp is the amount of second elapsed since basedate 1970-01-01. So you need in something (approximate, idea only) like `DATEADD(second, your_unix_timestamp, '1970-01-01 00:00:01')`.

Comment: arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int error

Comment: This is an idea, not a solution.